# how to find this limit : lim x to infinity

Tags: limits

how can I find this limit which is become infinite

$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(x(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x)\right)$

can I use conjugate method ?

that what I'm doing until now

$= x\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}-x}{1}\cdot \:\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}+x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+x}\right)\:$

$= x\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+x}\right)$

$= \left(\frac{x}{\left(\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^2}}+\frac{x}{x}\right)}\right)\:$

$= \:\left(\frac{x}{\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}+1\right)}\right)\:$

Comment: Alternately, let $x=\sinh t$, and use $\cosh t\pm\sinh t=e^{\pm x}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Using Conjugate.

$$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}x\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x\right) = \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}x\left[\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}-x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+x}\times \sqrt{x^2+1}+x\right]$$

So $$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}x\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+x}\right] = \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{x}{x\left[\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}+1\right]} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: This is not the question, though -- are you assuming a typo from the OP? (this is possible, maybe even likely; but then you should request clarification)

Comment: I did the same, to add another take on the question in case the OP *did* make a mistake when asking...

Comment: your first answer was correct!! 

when you multiply $\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x\right)$ with its conjugate  you left with $x$ in numerator not $x^3$

Comment: @user283144 What is the question you **intended** to ask? $(x\sqrt{x^2+1}-x)$ and $x(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x)$ are two different things.

Comment: it's $$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}x\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x\right)$$

Comment: Then, edit your question... this is not what you wrote there.

Comment: what is different between them! the both is the same

Comment: No.... in the first, $x$ is only multiplied to the square root.

Comment: you are right, what a silly mistake !!
so what the answer

Comment: $1/2$ (cf. juantheron's original answer, and the second part (now the only part) of mine.)

Comment: @juantheron I took the liberty of rolling back to your earlier revision, since the question has now been edited to be the one it answers.

Answer (score 3):

For the edited and corrected question, i.e. the limit at $\infty$ of 
$$
x\left(\sqrt{x^2+1} - x\right)
$$
indeed you can deal with this multiplying by the conjugate (cf. [jeantheron's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1494181/75808)). However, I would advocate for a more systematic approach, simple enough and highly generalizable. Assuming you have heard or will soon hear about [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem), you can do the following (detailing a lot each step):
$$\begin{align}
x\left(\sqrt{x^2+1} - x\right)
&= 
x\left(x\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}} - x\right)
= 
x\left(x\left(1+\frac{1}{2x^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right) - x\right)
\\
&= 
x\left(x+\frac{1}{2x}+o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) - x\right)
= 
x\left(\frac{1}{2x}+o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)
\\
&= 
\frac{1}{2}+o\left(1\right)
\end{align}$$
using that $(1+t)^\alpha = 1+\alpha t+o(t)$ when $t\to0$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use conjugates for $\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x\right)$ as follows

Notice, 
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}x\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x\right)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x\right)\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x\right)}{\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x\right)}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x(x^2+1-x^2)}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+x}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+x}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}+1}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+0}+1}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: in this step $= \:\left(\frac{x}{\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}+1\right)}\right)\:$ where that 1 on top come from? is it x?

Comment: Factoring the denominator by $x$, cancelling out with the numerator.

Comment: Notice, divide the numerator & denominator by $x$ as follows $$\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+x}=\frac{x/x}{\frac{1}{x}\sqrt{x^2+1}+\frac{x}{x}}$$$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^2}}+1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}+1}$$